# SELECT Statement with scalar variables in the middle

Tags: sql-server

So I am playing with this script on SQLZoo website https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_easy_questions
it works fine.

```
SELECT
    t.CountryRegion,
    t.CompanyName,
    t.Total
FROM
    (SELECT
         t.*,
         @counter := CASE
                        WHEN @CountryRegion = t.CountyRegion
                           THEN @counter + 1
                           ELSE 1
                     END AS counter,
         @CountryRegion := t.CountyRegion AS CountryRegion
     FROM
         (SELECT
              @counter := 0,
              @CountryRegion := 0) AS initvar,
         (SELECT
              Address.CountyRegion,
              Customer.CompanyName,
              SUM(SubTotal) AS 'Total'
          FROM
              SalesOrderHeader
          JOIN
              Customer ON SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
          JOIN
              CustomerAddress ON Customer.CustomerID = CustomerAddress.CustomerID
          JOIN
              Address ON CustomerAddress.AddressID = Address.AddressID
          GROUP BY
              Customer.CompanyName, Address.CountyRegion
          ORDER BY 
              Address.CountyRegion, SUM(SubTotal) DESC) AS t
    ) AS t
WHERE
    t.counter = 1;
```

I then run it against my local SQL Server 2017 `AdventureWorks` database (with proper database name), I got this error:

> Must declare scalar variable

What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what SQL language that site uses, but `@counter := 0` is not a valid TSQL statement. You have to use `declare` for each variable before you run a query using it.

Comment: I' ve tried your T-SQL Script at my local DB. Your syntax has some 'Syntax errors'. Can' t execute by SQL 2017 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is written for MySQL,not for SQL Server and is a way of getting the greatest n per group. With SQL Server you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  to get the greatest n per group, e.g.

```
SELECT
  t.CountryRegion,
  t.CompanyName,
  t.Total
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
          a.CountyRegion,
          c.CompanyName,
          SUM(SubTotal) AS Total,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.CountryRegion 
                            ORDER BY SUM(SubTotal)) AS Counter
        FROM SalesOrderHeader AS soh
          JOIN Customer AS c
            ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
          JOIN CustomerAddress AS ca
            ON c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID
          JOIN Address AS a
            ON ca.AddressID = a.AddressID
        GROUP BY c.CompanyName, a.CountyRegion
      ) AS t
WHERE t.Counter = 1;
```

Comment: @GraethD Thanks for the detail answer :D